# ValueError: Passing a dictionary input to a Sequential Model which doesn't have FeatureLayer as the first layer is an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I've tried running the following code, but got this error:

> File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 819, in fit
>   use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py",
>   line 235, in fit
>   use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py",
>   line 593, in _process_training_inputs
>   use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py",
>   line 706, in _process_inputs
>   use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py",
>   line 702, in **init**
>   x = standardize_function(x)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_v2.py",
>   line 660, in standardize_function
>   standardize(dataset, extract_tensors_from_dataset=False)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 2346, in _standardize_user_data
>   all_inputs, y_input, dict_inputs = self._build_model_with_inputs(x, y)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 2572, in _build_model_with_inputs
>   self._set_inputs(cast_inputs)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 2647, in _set_inputs
>   inputs = self._set_input_attrs(inputs)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py",
>   line 457, in _method_wrapper
>   result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
>   File
>   "C:\Users\TomerK\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py",
>   line 2681, in _set_input_attrs
>   raise ValueError('Passing a dictionary input to a Sequential Model '
>   ValueError: Passing a dictionary input to a Sequential Model which
>   doesn't have FeatureLayer as the first layer is an error.

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
#os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

try:
    model = keras.models.load_model("passrockmodel.h5")
except:
    print('\nDownloading Train Dataset...\n')
    train_dataset = tfds.load(name="rock_you", split="train[:75%]")
    assert isinstance(train_dataset, tf.data.Dataset)

    print('\nDownloading Test Dataset...\n')
    test_dataset = tfds.load("rock_you", split='train[-25%:]')
    assert isinstance(test_dataset, tf.data.Dataset)

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
    ])

    model.compile(
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'])


    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=20)

    model.save("passrockmodel.h5")


test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_dataset)

print('\nPredicting...\n')

predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)

print(predictions[0])
```

Comment: Does specifying the `input_shape` parameter of the first dense layer model help?

Comment: @JST99 I tried writing:         tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(train_dataset.shape[1],)),
but got another error instead: AttributeError: 'DatasetV1Adapter' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: I'm replying on my phone without a laptop to reproduce your code, so forgive me if I'm leading you in the wrong direction. However, it seems like `train_dataset` is not in numpy format. To call numpy's `shape` attribute on `train_dataset`, you might want to do something like `train_dataset = tfds.as_numpy(tfds.load(name="rock_you", split="train[:75%]"))`.

Comment: @JST99 I did only the `as_numpy` like you said, and got this error: `ValueError: Please provide model inputs as a list or tuple of 2 or 3 elements: (input, target) or (input, target, sample_weights) Received {'password': <tf.Tensor: shape=(8,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([100, 115,  98, 123, 122,  51,  57,  50], dtype=int64)>} `

Answer (score 2):

I've had your problem yesterday. Here's what solved it for me:

your first layer should be of type *tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures*

This first layer must be instantiated with an array of *tf.feature_column* objects. It happens that all my columns were numeric so my array was:

```
featureColumns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(columnNames[i], normalizer_fn= lambda x: (x - mean[i])/std[i]) for i in range(len(columnNames[:-1]))]
```

Note: the *normalizer_fn* arg is very useful as you can see, as well. It can eliminate the  need of any additional normalization preprocessing layer should you need it.

And so my layer became:

```
layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns=featureColumns, trainable=True)
```

I believe this should solve the error mentioned above in your question. Which is quoted as

> ValueError: Passing a dictionary input to a Sequential Model which
> doesn't have FeatureLayer as the first layer is an error.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention my columnNames array mentioned in the example has its label column name in the very end, that's why I used columnNames[:-1] for getting the keys for all the columns necessary to represent the featureColumns variable.